# Kubernetes rolling-update scheduled job

Tags: kubernetes

We now have [scheduled jobs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/scheduled-jobs/) in [Kubernetes 1.4](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/09/kubernetes-1.4-making-it-easy-to-run-on-kuberentes-anywhere.html)- is it possible to do a [rolling container update](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/rolling-updates/) (new image) against the cluster using this? The basic idea is I want a simple way to automatically roll out updates every set interval.

The 'traditional' way to do updates is for the CI to hit a webhook on the Kube master, but I want to avoid exposing services to the public and would rather just check for updates periodically.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's generally safe to expose your master server and send updates to it from your CI system, but you could definitely set up a scheduled job to update a [Deployment](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) to it's latest version. Kubernetes has a concept called [Service Accounts](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/) for authentication with the API from within the cluster and are integrated well with `kubectl` (i.e. it will use the service account info automatically to auth). The cluster also provides a `kubernetes` service for the master API. So you can deploy a container with `kubectl` and a script and use it to update the Deployment periodically.

You will need a mechanism to figure out what the latest version is. Maybe you could store the latest version info in a text file or something written to GCS or S3 and pull that file to get the latest version.

Say you have a deploy.yaml like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp:<latest-ver>
```

And then you can generate and update the Deployment in a script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -o VERSION http://url/to/VERSION
sed "s/<latest-ver>/$(cat VERSION)/" deploy.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

And build that into an image and run it as your scheduled job.